# How to add +/- 1% to a condition?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
      ID   Open  Close     SMA        EMA
30  UNITY  11.50  11.53  12.576  12.715570
31  UNITY  11.44  11.34  12.399  12.626823
32  UNITY  11.26  11.74  12.273  12.569609
33  UNITY  11.72  11.61  12.150  12.507699
34  UNITY  11.51  11.43  11.994  12.438170
35  UNITY  11.85  11.17  11.844  12.356352
```

How to make a condition which reflects if the close is +/- 1% or precisely equal to the EMA?

THANKS!

Comment: Please post your sample code.  The purpose of this site is not to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy.isclose(a, b, rtol=1e-02)`

`rtol` is the relative tolerance, which is 0.01 for +/- 1%.